# AppSync GraphQL map 1-1 to an existing GraphQL API

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I have an existing GraphQL API that exposes a schema like this:

```
type AType {
    id: Int!
    name: String!
    children: [BType]
}

type BType {
    id: Int!
    name: String!
}

type Query {
    a(id: ID): A
    as: [A]
}
```

plus some other omitted scalar fields in both. There are a couple of such API endpoints and I want to aggregate them all under a single AppSync instance, so that the front can query one endpoint with a single schema for all the data they need.

What I would like to do is if the front sends a query

```
as {
    id,
    name,
    children {
      id,
      name
    }
}
```

it would get relayed exactly to my existing GraphQL endpoint. The AWS examples linked on the AppSync page talk about GraphQL endpoints but the only linked code example is [this](https://github.com/amazon-archives/aws-appsync-refarch-microservices/blob/master/amplify/backend/api/StoreApi/resolvers/Query.listRecentOrders.req.vtl), and it shows a resolver like this:

```
#**
Make an arbitrary HTTP call when this field is listed in a query selection set.
The "relativePath" is the resource path relative to the root URL provided when you
created the HTTP data source. Pass a "params" object to forward headers, body,
and query parameters to the HTTP endpoint.
*#
#if($context.identity.sub == $context.args.userId) 
#set($payload = "query ListOrders {
  listOrders(
    userId: ""$context.args.userId""
    orderDateTimeStatus: {
        le : {
            orderDateTime: ""$context.args.orderDateTime""
        }
    }
    limit: 10
    
  ) {
    items {
      userId
      status
      orderDateTime
      details
      orderId
    }
    nextToken
  }
}")

{
    "version": "2018-05-29",
    "method": "POST",
    "resourcePath": "/graphql",
    "params":{
        "body": {
            "query": "$util.escapeJavaScript($payload)"
        },
        "headers":{
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "x-access-token" : "$context.request.headers.x-access-token"

        }
    }
}
#else 
  $utils.unauthorized() 
#end
```

This uses only the arguments passed into the query, not the query structure. If front requests a subset of fields of `A`, I only want to make a request for that subset of fields, not a request for all that then gets cut down by AppSync. Also it doesn't even contain nested objects -- would I have to fetch *all the children* every time just so that they get later ignored by AppSync?

Assume there are 4-5 microservices that have their own GraphQL endpoints that have different queries in their schemas. I'd like to map the requests 1-1 to them. How would I write such a resolver? AppSync doesn't really have a good playground environment where I could debug the resolver so I can't just look at the `$ctx` object and reverse-engineer the structure of the original query (AFAIK).

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60361326/proxy-request-to-graphql-server-through-aws-appsync) that asks just that, but the solution there doesn't work as intended, as mentioned by the author, and it seems to be dead.